# Do we need to unsubscribe to rxjs `from` operator

Tags: rxjs

when converting a promise to an observable with rxjs,

```
from(myPromise).subscribe(r => console.log(r))
```

do we need to unsubscribe to it ? or is it *safe* to assume it will always complete and never cause memory leak ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short: No

You do not need to unsubscribe from a promise. A promise should always complete or error, which causes the observable to complete or error as well.

There's no native way to cancel an in-flight promise, so unsubscribing from an observable that's wrapping a promise has no effect on the underlying promise.